# Report coming up blank using Java code, previews OK in the Studio

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Using a Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0 I created a very simple report with a static text and a red rectangle (as well as many other things I tested before). There is no query to fetch data, no dynamic field or anything.

This is what the design looks like:
[image]

Preview looks fine in all different formats (HTML, PDF etc..)
[image]

The problem I have comes when I try to generate the report in my web app. Using a library version 6.7.0.

HTML Export coded like this yields an empty String

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);
StringBuilder htmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();

SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration conf = new SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration();
conf.setHtmlHeader("");
conf.setBetweenPagesHtml("");
conf.setHtmlFooter("");
conf.setFlushOutput(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(conf);
SimpleHtmlExporterOutput output = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(htmlStringBuilder);
exporter.setExporterOutput(output);
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));

exporter.exportReport();
return htmlStringBuilder.toString(); // empty string
```

Eport to PDF using creates a single page PDF file. The page is blank.

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "file.pdf");
```

I tried to compile the JRXML file using both the Studio and also in the Java code. The result is still the same. JasperPrint object seem to be populated, however no elements are present on the page, which I reckon is related. Any chance to find out why? 
[image]

Comment: I have a feeling the 0 pages is because there is no datasource and no data getting in. Anything which would support that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options for this:

1. In your java code import the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource` class and fill the jasperPrint like so:

   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

   This should guarantee that your detail band is displayed once. This is what JasperSoft Studio uses when you preview a report with `One Empty Record` Data Adapter.
2. In JasperSoft Studio, move all the content out of the Detail band to Summary band, for example, and in Report Properties tab select:

   > When No Data Type: All Sections No Detail

   This way all the other bands, except the Detail one, will be rendered when you don't provide any data.